# How to strip specific tag into div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this **html** code

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <a href="" title="">My link</a>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <script>//This is a script</script>
</div>
```

And I this **javascript**:

```
$('.myDiv').children().each(
  function() {
     var strToStrip = $('.myDiv').html();
     if ( this.tagName != 'A' ) {
        // Strip tag element if tagName is not 'A'
        // and replace < or > with &lt; or &gt;
        strToStrip.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)(?!(a))/ig, "");
     }
  }
```

);

How can I strip all tags, except from the `a` element? 
I only need the link and strip tags if it is not a link tag.
I can't find what wrong with this code and what regex can I use to do this.

Any help please?

Comment: could you just take out all  the a tags or do you want the rest of the page?

Comment: Do you really need to convert the entire content of the div to a string before 'stripping'(by strip I assume you are referring to setting the content of each tag to ``) the html of each tag? If you are just trying to remove the html within each tag, besides `<a>`. Then adding an `id` to the `div` and `a` elements would leave you with some easy javascript. TBH, I have no clue what you are trying to ask

Comment: before i post an answer, I would like to know if you want to remove the `innerHtml` of the tags or remove the tags?

Comment: You know, I have a `textarea`, and the content of the text area will be set to the `div`, so if I enter an element in the textarea, it will be displayed in the `div`, if I enter a `script` element, that script will be executed, that why, I need to strip all tag, except for `a` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex example:

```
var strToStrip = $('.myDiv').html();
var temp = strToStrip.replace(/<[^a\/][a-z]*>/g, "&lt;");
var result = temp.replace(/<\/[^a][a-z]*>/g, "&gt;");
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thank you ... So if I want to replace < by "&lt;" and > "&gt;", is there a regex which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

My goal of this question is to figure out how twitter do his hashtag or usergroup by using `@` or `#`. Go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k35o9kmm/) to see the final result

Answer (score -1):

you can use replace method of string using regular expr

```
var html = $("#main").html();
var result = html.replace(/[\<\>\/]/g,'');
alert(result);
```

the example shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bnpdLcd2/)

Comment: I did it but I don't have the wanted result

Comment: @user3852377 how does this save the a tags ??

Comment: I use this regex: `/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g` and this remove all tag even the tag of link element

Comment: OP's question 'How can I strip all tags, except from the a element?'

Comment: Yeah, instead of striping `a` it remove tags, I don't find the best regex to do so! :(